# The Unsolved Maze With The Annoying Rhyme

Tags: riddle, pattern, rhyme, cipher

In 1989, someone going by the name [BLANK] made a maze game on the computer. It is said that the maze constantly changes its layout from time to time so that no one can make it to the end to claim the prize. Outside the maze on the wall, there is a cryptic message and some clues on how to beat the maze, but no one has cracked the code.

> GPTESTF
>   
> FKBNG
>   
> FKBNG
>   
> KWDR
>   
> NOW
>   
> 4303Q5
>   
> 020103112301180419
>
> Solving this puzzle isn’t hard
>   
> If you do, you will be rewarded with a crystal shard
>   
> Look down and you can see
>   
> The answer is in front of thee
>   
> The first step is never right
>   
> The second and third step is in the same direction that gives mankind light
>   
> The next line is the opposite if you believe
>   
> The forth step is the past tense of leave
>   
> Once you have solved all these clues
>   
> You are now halfway, don’t look so blue
>   
> Now listen carefully as this is tricky
>   
> Cause this maze is very picky
>   
> Listen to what the last three clues say
>   
> And you will be on your way
>   
> The fifth step is as you see
>   
> Next step is in the same direction as a falling tree
>   
> The last step must be split in pairs
>   
> Now there are two things you must compare
>   
> Once you solve this, you are done
>   
> Congratulations, you have won!

Can you solve the puzzle and get the crystal shard from the maze?

UPDATE:

> Please show how each step was deciphered, as well as, the direction to go to complete the maze.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first step is never right

> FORWARD (GPTESTF, taking keys to the left on keyboard)

The second and third step is in the same direction that gives mankind light

> RIGHT, RIGHT (FKBNG, taking keys left+up on keyboard)

The next line is the opposite if you believe
The forth step is the past tense of leave

> LEFT (KWDR, taking keys to the right on keyboard)

The fifth step is as you see

> NOW (NOW, taking as you see and as it is)

Next step is in the same direction as a falling tree

> REPEAT (4303Q5, taking keys right+down on keyboard)

The last step must be split in pairs

> BACKWARDS (substitution cipher, A=1, B=2, ...)

---

### Summary of solution:

> FORWARD, RIGHT, RIGHT, LEFT, LEFT, RIGHT, RIGHT, FORWARD

Comment: First one should be 1 letter to the right on the keyboard. That makes FORWARD out of GPTESTF

Comment: Then the actual solution is then WDDW (up right right up) because the 2 lefts and 2 of the rights cancel.

Answer (score 3):

Just eyeballing those encoded lines, I figure

> GPTESTF = **FORWARD** (first step is never right)
>  FKBNG = **RIGHT**
>  FKBNG = **RIGHT**
>  KWDR = **LEFT** (this fits with "past tense of leave" but is contradicted by the preceding line in the poem)
>  NOW = (probably) just the word **"now"** (it "is as you see")
>
>  **OK, this part of the solution I got from the one other answer:** *Apparently*, trees fall diagonally down to the right. On a keyboard, diagonally down to the right from the keys 4303Q5 is **REPEAT**
>
>  The last one (020103112301180419) "split in pairs", yields the A = 1, B = 2, etc. number codes for "**BACKWARDS**"

Put these all together and

> FORWARD RIGHT RIGHT LEFT (and then REPEAT BACKWARDS, which gives us) LEFT RIGHT RIGHT FORWARD
>
>  Though I don't know what the rule is that changes the encoding between the first and second and between the third and fourth lines. Below is the regular alphabet, and then the letters each letter is encoded as in lines 1, 2 **and** 3, and 4, respectively.
>
>   `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
>   `S__F_G________P__T____E___`
>   `______BNK________F_G______`
>   `____WD_____K_______R______`